# Prime numbers loop returning blank string

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public String primeNumbers()
{
    //create variable to be returned
    String prime = "";
    int num = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.limit; i++)
    {
        num = this.limit - i;
        for(int count = 2; count < this.limit; count++)
        {
            if ( num % count == 0)
            {
                count = this.limit + 1;

            }
            else if ( num == count)
            {
                prime += num + ", ";
            }

        }


    }


    return prime;
}
```

The goal of this is to produce a list of prime numbers in between 1 and the upper limit which is the private variable limit.  However, when I run the code, I get a blank message as a return.  Why is this?

Comment: What's the value of this.limit?

Comment: It's any positive number

Comment: What is the number when you test the code?  My bet is you haven't set it and so it is 0, and hence you get a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the logic of your code, but having helper methods is good.

```
public String primeNumbers()
{
    //create variable to be returned
    String prime = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < this.limit; i++)
    {
        if(this.isPrime(i)){
            prime += i + ", ";
        }
    }
    return prime;
}

private boolean isPrime(int number){
    if(number <= 1){
        return false;
    } else if(number == 2){
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++){
        if(number%i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The isPrime() is naive, and can definitely be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

There was a question about this yesterday and I ended up writing this as a refresher for myself.

```
 public class Erasthotenes
    {
        private int range;
        private boolean[] nums;

        public Erasthotenes(int range)
        {
            this.range = range;
            nums = new boolean[range];
            for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
            {
                nums[i] = true;
            }
            nums[0] = nums[1] = false;
        }

        public void sieve()
        {
            int root = (int) Math.sqrt(range);
            for(int i = 2; i < root; ++i)
            {
                for(int j = i + 1; j < range; ++j)
                {
                    if(j % i == 0)
                    {
                        nums[j] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void printPrimes()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
            {
                if(nums[i] == true)
                {
                    System.out.print(i + ", ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes